# To initialize the billId value as Billid='BID0' in c#.net

Tags: .net, c#-2.0

i used to increment the *BillId* from my table *Hbill*.I called the increment() to increase my billid like BID1,BID2.....
The below code is working  but when entering the first record,its showing error since the billid is null.How can i **initialize the billId value as Billid='BID0' or any other way to set the default value while starting.**

```
public void increment()
    {
        con.Open();           

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Max(billid) from hbill ", con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                id = dr[0] as string;

                //department = reader[1] as string;

            }

            cur_id = IncrementID(id, 3);                       


    con.Close();
}


static string IncrementID(string startValue, int numNonDigits)
        {
            string nonDigits = startValue.Substring(0, numNonDigits);
            int len = startValue.Length - numNonDigits;
            int number = int.Parse(startValue.Substring(numNonDigits));
            number++;
            if (number >= Math.Pow(10, len)) number = 1; // start again at 1
            return String.Format("{0}{1:D" + len.ToString() + "}", nonDigits, number);
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you just initialize `id` to "BID0"?

Comment: hi its showing following error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" in this line : string nonDigits = startValue.Substring(0, numNonDigits);